# Static content separation in JSF2.0 project

Tags: jsf-2

I need your help on below.

I have JSF2.0 application which runs on WAS8.5. I want to separate the static and dynamic contents as we want to use WAS server only for dynamic contents and IHS to server static contents for my application. My current architecture and design as follows:

1. Marked file serving flag as false in ibm-web-ext.xml file (IBM config file to say whether WAS to be served static content or Not).
2. We’ve used core JSF2.0 tages (h:outputStylesheet, h:outputScript and h:graphicImage) and also traditional html tags some places (link, script and img) to load static contents.

My understanding/Observation is, 
1.  When we load static contents using JSF2.0 components (styles using h:outputStylesheet component, java scripts using h:outputScript and images using h:graphicImage), all static contents will be served by WAS server as FacesServlet is responsible for reading the component and loading the resources accordingly. According to the JSF2.0 guidelines&standard, we should use JSF tags to load the resources like js, css and images.
2.  When we load static contents using html tags, all the static contents served by webserver ie IHS

Now my question is,
My application is internet channel application where we want to serve the possible as quickly as possible. Technically, I want to use Core JSF tags wherever possible and use the WAS server to serve only dynamic contents to reduce the load.

Please advice me options to meet my requirement.

Thanks,
Nanjundan Chinnasamy

Answer (score 0):

We have made the following code changes to achieve our requirement.

To server all images by IHS, 
Use native JSF2.0 tag with value attribute like below.

This will generate the html source like below

We used the traditional html tags (used in JSF1.X) versions to load css and java script files like below

If we use h:outputScript and h:outputStylesheet tags available in JSF2.0, we have a name attribute which marked as mandatory.  We unable to make it static reference using value attribute alone. We don’t have much documentation at MyFaces site to give references to you. Mean time, you can have a look the following: 
https://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/tagdoc/h_outputScript.html 
https://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/tagdoc/h_outputStylesheet.html

If you any other suggestion/comments, please do let me know. We will revert you with an update.

Thanks,
Nanjundan Chinnasamy